# how to loop inside the table with all of checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to loop inside the table with all of the checkboxes and entering the 1 and 0 on based of checkbox state into the SQL database (code in c#)

```
protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow g1 in GridView1.Rows)
        {

            DO objDB = new DO();
            int quater1 = (g1.FindControl("Q1CheckBox") as CheckBox).Checked == true? 1 : 0;
            int quater2 = (g1.FindControl("Q2CheckBox") as CheckBox).Checked == true? 1 : 0;
            int quater3 = (g1.FindControl("Q3CheckBox") as CheckBox).Checked == true? 1 : 0;
            int quater4 = (g1.FindControl("Q4CheckBox") as CheckBox).Checked == true? 1 : 0;           

            string query = @"update TimeLine SET Quater1="+quater1+ ",Quater2=" + quater1 + ",Quater3=" + quater1 + ",Quater4=" + quater1 + "";
            objDB.ExcuteQuery(query);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you be bit more clear on exactly what is the query - maybe detail it out a bit

Comment: Which error to you get? Please share more details

Comment: it is not showing any error, but the data entering into the database is zeros in all the columns of table

Comment: Can you share what the DO is?   It doesn't seem like you've opened a database connection yet and also you want to ExecuteNonQuery()